# Serialization of a class cause error

Tags: vb.net, windows, universal, serialization

Windows 10 universal app. VB

I have the class below which I want to save to file and read from file, Saving works but when I attempt to load I get the error.

> Message=Error in line 1 position 249. Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/KoW_Universal_v2:MagicItem' contains data of the 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringMagicItemyoeMIiQz' data contract. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this contract. Add the type corresponding to 'ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringMagicItemyoeMIiQz' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.
>     Source=System.Private.DataContractSerialization

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports Windows.Storage

Public Class MagicItem
     Property MagicItemName As String
     Property MagicItemCost As Integer
     Property MagicItemDescripyion As String
     Property LimitToHero As Boolean
    Property LimitToSpecialRule As String 'key to the special rule 

End Class



Public Class clsMagicItems
    Private MagicItems As New Dictionary(Of String, MagicItem)

Async Sub SaveMagicItems()
    ' StorageFile File = Await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    Dim myfile As StorageFile
    myfile = Await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("MagicItems.dat", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)

    Dim KnownTypeList As New List(Of Type)
    KnownTypeList.Add(GetType(clsMagicItems))
    KnownTypeList.Add(GetType(MagicItem))

    Dim r As Streams.IRandomAccessStream
    r = Await myfile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite)
    Using outStream As Streams.IOutputStream = r.GetOutputStreamAt(0)
        Dim serializer As New DataContractSerializer(GetType(clsMagicItems), KnownTypeList)
        serializer.WriteObject(outStream.AsStreamForWrite(), MagicItems)
        Await outStream.FlushAsync()
        outStream.Dispose()
        r.Dispose()
    End Using
End Sub
Async Sub LoadMagicItems()
    Try
        Dim myfile As Stream

        Dim KnownTypeList As New List(Of Type)
        KnownTypeList.Add(GetType(clsMagicItems))
        KnownTypeList.Add(GetType(MagicItem))

        Dim serializer As New DataContractSerializer(GetType(clsMagicItems), KnownTypeList)
        myfile = Await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync("MagicItems.dat")
        'LINE BELOW RAISE ERROR
        MagicItems = serializer.ReadObject(myfile)
    Catch
        'failed to load the file
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, should have had the following code

```
 KnownTypeList.Add(GetType(Dictionary(Of String, MagicItem)))
 ...
 Dim serializer As New DataContractSerializer(GetType(Dictionary(Of String, MagicItem)), KnownTypeList)
```